# How to serialize an interface such as IList<T>

Tags: c#, list, interface, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to serialize an IList<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464525/how-to-serialize-an-ilistt)

I wish to serialize an class (let's call it `S`) that contains a property of the type `IList<T>` where `T` is another class which I have defined. I get an exception when I attempted to serialize an instance of class `S` to XML. This is understandable as the `XmlSerializer` doesn't know which concrete class to use. Is there a way, hopefully using attributes, to specify which concrete class to instantiate when serializing/deserializing an instance. My implementation of class `S` creates a instance of the `List<T>` class. Here is some code to illustrate my example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[Serializable]
public class T { }

[Serializable]
public class S
{
    public IList<T> ListOfTs { get; set; }

    public S()
    {
        ListOfTs = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        S s = new S();
        s.ListOfTs.Add(new T());
        s.ListOfTs.Add(new T());
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(S));
        serializer.Serialize(new StringWriter(), s);
    }
}
```

I'm hoping there's an attribute I can place above the `ListOfTs` definition that says to the serialize, "assume an instance of `List<T>` when serializing/deserializing".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the

```
public IList<T> ListOfTs { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<T> ListOfTs { get; set; }
```

Then it will work.

Comment: I would do this, except this would change the interface for the `S` class. While this is unlikely to have practical impact, but from point of principle, I'd like to see if there's a way to solve the problem without changing the type.

Comment: The suggested solution, although is the working one, may ruin your public API architecture

Answer (score 3):

I think there's 2 ways that are generally approached for this kind of problem.

One would be to use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), but since you're already using XmlSerializer, you probably don't want to do that.

The "alternative" is to have a property that is used specifically for the purpose of serialization, and to ignore the IList during serialization.

```
[Serializable]
public class S
{
    IList<T> _listofTs;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IList<T> ListOfTs { get _listofTs; set _listofTs = value; }

    [XmlElement(Name="Not Exactly the Greatest Solution!")]
    public List<T> ListOfTs { get _listofTs; set _listofTs = value; }

    public S()
    {
        ListOfTs = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using XmlIgnore attribute on a property will totally ignore it. The questions is to include the interface property in the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface and implement the serialization logic manually using Xml readers and writers.