# How to deserialize child elements of different types into list/collection of base type which is a property of the corresponding class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have a legacy system that uses some data that is stored in XML format. The format of the XML cannot be changed without causing critical issues (i.e. tooling and other software that reads the format).

The XML is structured like this:

```
<Things>
    <ThingOne Name="FirstThing">
        <ThingOne Name="FirstChildThing" />
        <ThingTwo Name="SecondChildThing"/>
    </ThingOne>
    <ThingTwo Name="SecondThing">
        <ThingOne Name="ThirdChildThing"  />
        <ThingTwo Name="FourthChildThing" />
    </ThingTwo>
</Things>
```

In my scenario "ThingOne" and "ThingTwo" are classes that extend "SomeThing".
Like this:

```
public abstract class SomeThing 
{
    public int ItemNumber {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<SomeThing> ChildThings {get; set;}
    public abstract void InspectChildren();
}

public sealed class ThingOne : SomeThing
{
    public override void InspectChildren()
    {
        /*Iterates Child Things and performs actions*/
    }
}

public sealed class ThingTwo : SomeThing
{
    public override void InspectChildren()
    {
        /*Iterates Child Things and performs actions different from thing one*/
    }
}
```

And "Things" is a class with a collection of "SomeThing":

```
public sealed class Things
{
    /*Thing One and Thing Two should be deserialized to here*/
    public List<SomeThing> ThingItems {get; set;}
}
```

There is a thing inspector like this:

```
public static ThingInspector
{
    public static void InspectThings(IEnumerable<SomeThing> thingsToInspect)
    {
        foreach(var thing in thingsToInspect)
        {
            thing.InspectChildren()
        }
    }
}
```

However when I use the XmlSerializer to deserialize the XML into an instance of "Things" it doesn't pickup "ThingOne" and "ThingTwo" and add them into ThingItems.

I have tried decorating the classes as follows:

```
public sealed class Things:IList<SomeThing>
{
    /*Thing One and Thing Two should be deserialized to here*/
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ThingOne), ElementName = "ThingOne")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ThingTwo), ElementName = "ThingTwo")]
    public List<SomeThing> ThingItems {get; set;}

    /*Example doesn't include IList implementation, but it is present and correct*/
}


public abstract class SomeThing 
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int ItemNumber {get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ThingOne), ElementName = "ThingOne")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ThingTwo), ElementName = "ThingTwo")]
    public List<SomeThing> ChildThings {get; set;}
    
    public abstract void InspectChildren();
}
```

The deserialized object is an instance of "Things", but ThingItems is empty.

What am I missing? I have tried changing the xml format so that "ThingOne" and "ThingTwo" are wrapped in a "ThingItems" list and that works fine, but the xml format in the production system cannot be changed without causing failures with other software that is reading and writing the xml data.

My problem is that I need to deserialize the child elements of "Things" into a list on the corresponding "Things" class instead of forcing the object structure onto the XML. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It cannot be done.  To create your list you would need a base class and two inherited classes which would require a type attribute added to the xml and to use [XmlInclude].  Since you cannot change the xml there is no solution.  Without XmlInclude you would have one c# property and two xml tag names.  You cannot map one-to-two without a way of indicating which type to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize your XML by modifying your types as follows:

```
public interface IHasThings
{
    List<SomeThing> ChildThings { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Things")]
public class Things : IHasThings
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(ThingOne), ElementName = "ThingOne")]
    [XmlElement(typeof(ThingTwo), ElementName = "ThingTwo")]
    public List<SomeThing> ChildThings { get; set; } = new List<SomeThing>();
}

public abstract class SomeThing : IHasThings
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [XmlElement(typeof(ThingOne), ElementName = "ThingOne")]
    [XmlElement(typeof(ThingTwo), ElementName = "ThingTwo")]
    public List<SomeThing> ChildThings {get; set;} = new List<SomeThing>();

    public abstract void InspectChildren();
}
```

Notes:

- By applying [`[XmlElementAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to your lists, the list elements will be serialized as immediate children of the parent's element without inserting an extra, intermediate container element.
- Polymorphism is handled by applying [`[XmlElement(typeof(TThing), ElementName = "ThingName")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute__ctor_System_String_System_Type_) which specifies an alternate XML element, name for that specific polymorphic child type, similarly to how [`XmlArrayItemAttribute(String, Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlArrayItemAttribute__ctor_System_String_System_Type_)  works for collections with a container element.  `XmlArrayItem` and `XmlElement` should not be applied to the same property.
- Introduction of `IHasThings` is optional but may make it easier to traverse your hierarchy, treating the root container and child things in a uniform manner.
- `ThingOne` and `ThingTwo` are unchanged.
- A good way to debug issues in XML deserialization is to manually construct your expected deserialization graph, and then serialize it.  Any divergences between the observed and expected XML likely indicate where your deserialization bug lies.  With your data model you would have seen an extra level of container element `<ChildThings>` for the child collections.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LAx0vN).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I had already tried the "XmlElement" attribute before I settled on "XmlArrayItem" so I changed them back and tried again, but my tests were still failing. Because my tests were still failing and the only difference between your implementation and mine was that I implemented "IList<>" on my class (your example does not) I just removed "IList<>" from the class declaration and it started working.

Comment: So I guess my issue was that I was trying to implement IList. It is fine though because I can just encapsulate the data class inside a list adapter or something when I build my solution. The key was being able to support the previous version of data storage and this solution accomplishes that nicely

Comment: @JD- - It's true you cannot serialize an interface with `XmlSerializer`, see [How to serialize an interface such as IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10012736/3744182).  You can only serialize concrete classes.  I didn't realize you were also having that problem.   Finally, if your question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).